# Difference between UISearchBar and UISearchBarController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar

I'm confused as to what the difference between a `UISearchBar/UISearchBarDelegate` and a `UISearchBarController` is.

Right now, this is what I'm doing to implement my search bar:

```swift
class SearchViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
}

extension SearchViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        if !searchBar.text!.isEmpty {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "Search", sender: searchBar.text!)
        }
    }
}
```

I've seen people online doing things like:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

What is the difference between this and what I'm doing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question is kind of similar to asking "What is the difference between `UIView` and `UIViewController`?"

`UISearchBar` is a *view*. It has a text field and (optionally) a button, and that's pretty much it.

`UISearchController` is a *controller* that controls the more abstract behaviour of "searching". One of its jobs is to control the behaviour of its `searchBar`, but it has many other jobs too, such as telling the `searchResultsUpdater` that it should update the search results (because the text in the search bar has changed, or whatever). It also exposes properties like `obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation` and `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` to control how the views should look when the search bar is the first responder.

If you are directly using `UISearchBar`, then you need to manually implement all these things that the `UISearchController` does for you. This could be desired if your intention is to create your own kind of searching behaviour that the `UISearchController` doesn't provide, but if you just want a plain old search feature in your app, use `UISearchController` because it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: That makes sense @Sweeper, thanks!  So if I was to implement what I'm doing with a `UISearchController`, how would I do that?  Have my `SearchViewController` class inherit from `UISearchController` and set up the search bar programmatically?

Comment: @SamFlattery Do `let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)` and add `searchController.searchBar` as a subview of something. Make your VC conform to `UISearchResultsUpdating` and set `self` as `searchController.searchResultsUpdater`. You can find lots of tutorials online about how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly.

- `UIxxx` is the class of objects rendered on screen, (`UIButton`, etc)
- `UIxxxController` is the class of objects that coordinates objects on screen (receive events, etc.)
- `UIxxxDelegate` the class of objects that embed functional code to let `UIxxx` objects behave the way you want (fill content, etc).

Your code looks like you connected things via IB. The code found on internet looks like the controller is built directly in the code and not via IB; the `UISearchController` is instanciated.

Comment: So the UISearchBar that I have on my storyboard is the same thing as if I had instantiated it like UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)?

Comment: No, the `UISearchBar` is the object with which user sees (the rendering) and the `UISearchController` is the object that mostly implements the functional logic of searching (mediating the logic in between the search bar, the search logic and the display of results).